# Sonar 5.6 : cannot update issue

Tags: sonarqube, issue-tracking, sonarqube5.6

I try to update an issue on the UI (assign/set severity/open). But nothing append.
When i see the network exchange i have a 404:
{"errors":[{"msg":"Issue with key '76b53a17-fa8f-4d04-b999-1fd5e401fee0' does not exist"}]}

But i found my issue in my database (mysql):

```
mysql> select kee from issues where kee='76b53a17-fa8f-4d04-b999-1fd5e401fee0';
+--------------------------------------+
| kee                                  |
+--------------------------------------+
| 76b53a17-fa8f-4d04-b999-1fd5e401fee0 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

We try to find the query executed my sonar. We just find it on the head version of sonar (IssueFinder and IBatis config) and it's work:

```
select i.id,
i.kee as kee,
i.rule_id as ruleId,
i.severity as severity,
i.manual_severity as manualSeverity,
i.message as message,
i.line as line,
i.locations as locations,
i.gap as gap,
i.effort as effort,
i.status as status,
i.resolution as resolution,
i.checksum as checksum,
i.assignee as assignee,
i.author_login as authorLogin,
i.tags as tagsString,
i.issue_attributes as issueAttributes,
i.issue_creation_date as issueCreationTime,
i.issue_update_date as issueUpdateTime,
i.issue_close_date as issueCloseTime,
i.created_at as createdAt,
i.updated_at as updatedAt,
r.plugin_rule_key as ruleKey,
r.plugin_name as ruleRepo,
r.language as language,
p.kee as componentKey,
i.component_uuid as componentUuid,
p.module_uuid as moduleUuid,
p.module_uuid_path as moduleUuidPath,
p.path as filePath,
root.kee as projectKey,
i.project_uuid as projectUuid,
i.issue_type as type
from issues i
    inner join rules r on r.id=i.rule_id
    inner join projects p on p.uuid=i.component_uuid
    inner join projects root on root.uuid=i.project_uuid
where i.kee='76b53a17-fa8f-4d04-b999-1fd5e401fee0';
```

it's return one row.
What can i do? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ES folder is probably corrupted. Here are the steps to clean it up :

1. Stop the SonarQube server
2. Remove the {SONARQUBE_INSTALLATION}/data/es folder
3. Restart the server